# Why does Ruby /[[:punct:]]/ miss some punctuation characters?

Tags: ruby, regex, posix

Ruby `/[[:punct:]]/` is supposed to match all "punctuation characters". According to [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Regular_expressions#POSIX_character_classes), this means `` /[\]\[!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^_`{|}~-]/ `` per POSIX standard.

It matches: `-[]\;',./!@#%&*()_{}::"?`.

However, it does *not* match: `` =`~$^+|<> `` (at least in ruby 1.9.3p194).

What gives?

Comment: My glibc documentation says the `[[:punct:]]` should match anything that `wctype(3)` calls a punctuation mark; the `ispunct(3)` page says `checks for any printable character which is not a space or an alphanumeric character.`. That seems pretty explicit.

Comment: [Ruby's RE engine is special, though](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt) -- there is documentation on both Unicode-case and not-Unicode-case for the `punct` class. I'm still not sure what this means, specifically, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 11):

The punctuation character class is defined by the locale. The Open Group [LC_TYPE definition for punct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) says:

> Define characters to be classified as punctuation characters. In the POSIX locale, neither the `<space>` nor any characters in classes alpha, digit, or cntrl shall be included. In a locale definition file, no character specified for the keywords upper, lower, alpha, digit, cntrl, xdigit, or as the  shall be specified.

Basically, it defines how *punct* can be defined by exluding other character classes, but it doesn't actually define the punctuation symbols directly--that's the locale's job.

I couldn't find a canonical reference to what is in each locale. Maybe someone else knows. Meanwhile, you can find an LC_TYPE that matches the *punct* character class you want, or just specify the class directly.

Comment: FWIW, my locale is Rails' default `en` (also same is true with non-Rails plain irb, and my OS is `en_US`). Any suggestions on how to fix this (other than just being explicit)? I'm hoping there aren't more random gotchas…

Answer (score 2):

The greater than symbol is in the ["Symbol, Math" category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm), not the punctuation category. You can see this if you force the regex's encoding to UTF-8 (it defaults to the source encoding, and presumably your source is UTF-8 encoded, while my default source is something else):

```
2.1.2 :004 > /[[:punct:]]/u =~ '<'
 => nil 
2.1.2 :005 > /[[:punct:]]/ =~ '<'
 => 0
```

If you force the regex to ASCII encoding (/n - more options [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options)) you'll see it categorize '<' in punct, which I think is what you want. However, this will probably cause problems if your source contains characters outside the ASCII subset of UTF-8.

```
2.1.2 :009 > /[[:punct:]]/n =~ '<'
 => 0
```

A better solution would be to use the 'Symbol' category instead in your regex instead of the 'punct' one, which matches '<' in UTF-8 encoding:

```
2.1.2 :012 > /\p{S}/u =~ '<'
 => 0
```

There's a longer list of categories [here](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

Comment: Symbol does not include actual punctuations such as `,.:"`. A combination of the 2 covers all the "punctuation" characters (as defined by POSIX) in ASCII range. However, currency signs, copyright sign, arrows and various other symbols will also be included if we use a combination of Symbol and Punctuation general category.