# Regular expression in Ruby to capture Unicode punctuation marks?

Tags: ruby, regex

Is there a regular expression in Ruby that identifies Unicode punctuation (e.g., ",-)?

Comment: You could just place all the punctuation you want to match in a [character class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Character+Classes). According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Character+Properties) `/\p{P}/` should match unicode characters. But maybe POSIX `/[[:punct:]]/` will do? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11130490/789593

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\p{P}
```

- not just in Ruby. 
See http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use this one:

```
/[[:punct:]]/
```

For more info check the [Regexp class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html). You can also test it on this [Rubular permalink](http://rubular.com/r/DHt8RHjWYH)

Comment: Note: this won't match some 'punctuation' characters like `=` depending on your locale.