# Regex "punct" character range results in warning about duplicate range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rspec

I have a simply library that is intended to create safe slugs for a rails project. The RSpec test looks like this:

```
RSpec.describe SlugSupport do
  it 'filters out punctuation' do
    expect(SlugSupport.slugify('`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:",./<>?:\'\/\\')).to be_nil
  end
end
```

and the implementation looks like:

```
class SlugSupport
  def self.slugify str
    slug = str.to_s.downcase.strip
    tmp = slug.gsub(/[[:punct:]\s`$<>^|+=~]+/, '-').gsub(/^[-]+/, '')
    tmp.empty? ? nil : tmp
  end
end
```

With this implementation the test works, but results in a warning.

```
lib/slug_support.rb:8: warning: character class has duplicated range: /[[:punct:]\s`$<>^|+=~]+/
```

However, when I remove the additional characters from the Regex

```
slug.gsub(/[[:punct:]\s]+/, '-').gsub(/^[-]+/, '')
```

I get no warning but the test fails with:

```
1) SlugSupport filters out punctuation
 Failure/Error: expect(SlugSupport.slugify('`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|[]\:",./<>?:\'\/\\')).to be_nil
   expected: nil
        got: "`~-$-^-+-=-|-<>-"
 # ./spec/lib/slug_support_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

From other SO questions (e.g. [Why does Ruby /[[:punct:]]/ miss some punctuation characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130490/why-does-ruby-punct-miss-some-punctuation-characters) ) the [:punct] character group is behaving correctly for my locale, I think. So the question: is the warning incorrect? And, if the warning is incorrect, which part of the stack generates that warning, RSpec, Rails or Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that warning in my locale, but what I would assume is that not all of the characters are in `[[:punct:]]`.  Just remove the ones that are; you can use something like this to figure out which those are:

```
ruby -e 'puts "`$<>^|+=~".chars.grep /[[:punct:]]/'
```

Comment: That returns what I'd expect: none of the chars are in the [:punct] group which makes me thing the warning is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe the Rails app is using a different environment than the one you're checking in?  You could try running that `puts` command in the Rails console to be sure.