# Regex "punct" character class matches different characters depending on Ruby version

Tags: ruby, regex, posix

Ruby's character classes for *punctuation characters*, i.e. `[:punct:]`, `\p{Punct}`, or `\p{P}` seem to match different characters depending on the Ruby version I'm using.

Here's a little example: (sorry for messing with SO's syntax highlighter)

```
# punct.rb
chars = <<-EOD.split
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~
EOD

matched, not_matched = chars.partition { |c| c =~ /[[:punct:]]/ }

puts "    matched: #{matched.join}"
puts "not matched: #{not_matched.join}"
```

With Ruby 1.9.3 and again with Ruby 2.4.0 I get:

```
    matched: !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~
not matched:
```

But various Ruby versions in-between (2.0.x, 2.1.x, 2.2.x, 2.3.x) give me:

```
    matched: !"#%&'()*,-./:;?@[]_{}
not matched: $+<=>^`|~
```

Why is this happening and what is the correct behavior? And even more important: how can I achieve a consistent result across Ruby versions?

Trying to change my locale was to no avail (as suggested by [Why does Ruby /[[:punct:]]/ miss some punctuation characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11130490/477037)).

Comment: Are you only interested in the regex compatibility with the listed ASCII punctuation symbols?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is the actual problem I'm trying to solve but any additional information about Ruby's regex oddities would be great.

Comment: You may use `[[:punct:]$+<=>^\`|~]` to make it consistent in all the Ruby versions (if you plan to match punctuation symbols that were matched with the POSIX compliant `[:punct:]` POSIX character class). To make it compatible with `\p{P}`, use `(?![$+<=>^\`|~])[[:punct:]]`.

Comment: I think this is relevant: https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/issues/42

Comment: @matt it is, setting either the string's or script's encoding to US-ASCII seems to fix the problem in 2.0-2.3. Would you like to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 used US_ASCII as its default encoding, which properly matched all punctuation. Ruby 2.0 switched its default encoding to UTF-8, introducing the bug you discovered, which causes punctuation to be improperly matched. Ruby 2.4 patched this bug.

The correct behavior would be to match all punctuation, as ruby 1.9.3 and 2.4 do. This is consistent with the POSIX regex definition for punctuation.

One choice for making your code consistent is to encode all strings as US_ASCII or an alternative which doesn't have the UTF-8 bug:

`matched, unmatched = chars.partition { |c| c.encode(Encoding::US_ASCII) =~ /[[:punct:]]/ }`

But that's probably not desirable because it forces you to use a restrictive encoding for your strings.

The other option is to manually define the punctuation:

```
/[!"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]/
```

It's somewhat inelegant, but you can throw it into a variable and add it to regexes that way:

```
punctuation = "[!\"\#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@\[\\\]^_`{|}~]"
my_regex = /#{punctuation}/
```

Comment: Don't forget that `Regexp.escape` and `Regexp.union` exist.