# Regex incorrectly matching punctuation (including spaces)

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to check if a string contains at least one lowercase letter, uppercase letter, and a number, but not punctuation (including spaces).

For example

- `4aBc8Fk3` should match
- `4aBc 8.;3` should not match

I tried the following, but it matches spaces:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}[^[:punct:]]$
```

Any ideas how to not match strings containing punctuation including spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression you have got there does the following for as far as I understand (I'm not familiar with the ruby variety, and still quite new to regex myself; this will give you an idea, but may not be 100% correct):

1. Go to the beginning of the string
2. Ensure the string matches any number of any characters followed by a lowercase letter, e.g. `--a`
3. Ensure the string matches any number of any characters followed by an uppercase letter, e.g.`--aA`
4. Ensure the string matches any number of any characters followed by a number, e.g. `--aA0`
5. If that is all true, make sure the beginning of the string is followed by at least 6 random characters, e.g.`--aA0-`
6. Ensure that is followed by a single non-punctuation character (although this is the part I'm not sure about, as I haven't used character classes before, and don't know if it's `[^[:punct:]]` or `[^:punct:]`), e.g. `--aA0-c`
7. Ensure that is followed directly by the end of the string

Now, the lookaheads would also allow a different order of occurrences, e.g. `0---Aa`, as long as the string contains any characters followed by what they are looking for.

What you probably want is `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$`, i.e. at least six characters, with the characters being letters and numbers (though that would also allow `aaaaaa`, for example).

Maybe try `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$` to make sure each group is present, and to get alpha-numerical characters (at least six of them) only.

I always use a tool such as http://www.regexpal.com/ to slowly build up my regex and to see where I go wrong, deconstructing a "bad" regex until I get to a "good" one, then slowly adding to it again.

Hope that helps. :)

P.S.: I'm still a bit unclear how many characters you want to match in total, i.e. if the string is fixed length or not...?

Comment: The full requirements are: At least six characters long, contains a lowercase letter, contains an uppercase letter, contains a number. But in my version its accepting spaces & punctuations

Comment: So, according to this, in your case, POSIX character classes might be a bad idea anyway, as they are driven by locale: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11130562/2018047
And `[[:punct:]]` is likely not checking for spaces: http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html

Comment: At least six alphanumerical characters, or at least six characters, as long as they are neither punctuation nor space? E.g., is `€` valid?

Comment: At least six alphanumerical characters.

Comment: Didn't think about adding the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` in there as well

Comment: By the way, in my experience with regex on bash, look-arounds are quite expensive operations. Things usually got a lot faster by piping (nesting) several regex together... :)