# Ruby Regexp not matching unicode quotes with POSIX bracket expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use the `[[:punct:]]` POSIX bracket expression on a more complex regular expression, and I've found it is related with the following problem:

I've ran this on a Ruby's 2.4.4 irb console, producing a valid match:

```
irb(main):001:0> " >text" =~ /[[:punct:]]text/
=> 1
```

However, if I add a UTF8 quote character (`”`), it won't match:

```
irb(main):002:0> "” >text" =~ /[[:punct:]]text/
=> nil
```

But if I use a `.` instead of a `>`, it does work as I'm expecting:

```
irb(main):003:0> " .text" =~ /[[:punct:]]text/
=> 1
irb(main):004:0> "” .text" =~ /[[:punct:]]text/
=> 2
```

I'm not trying to find a workaround for this, but trying to understand why is not matching on the second case.

Comment: `[13] pry(main)> "” >text" =~ /[[:punct:]]text/ #=> 2` works for me

Comment: What ruby version do you use? 4.4.5 seems more a rails version, not a ruby version.

Comment: @mrzasa Sorry, I've updated the question. Ruby's version is 2.4.4, installed with `rbenv`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the POSIX bracket expressions `[[:punct:]]` it may match different characters.
You can find some detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130490/why-does-ruby-punct-miss-some-punctuation-characters).

To find out which category a character is in your local try [A Unicode character's General Category](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

For example, using ruby 2.2.4:

```
irb(main):001:0> /[[:punct:]]/n =~ '<'
=> nil
```

But if I use the Symbol General Category

```
irb(main):002:0> /\p{S}/u =~ '<'
=> 0
```